# protobuf-csharp-port

Tags: c#, .net, networkstream, protocol-buffers

I'm using Jon Skeet's (excellent) port of Google's Protocol Buffers to C#/.Net.

For practice, I have written a dummy Instant Messenger app that sends some messages down a socket. I have a message definition as follows:-

```
message InstantMessage {<br/>
  required string Message = 1;<br/>
  required int64 TimeStampTicks = 2; <br/>
}
```

When the sender serialises the message, it sends it really elegantly:-

```
        ...
        InstantMessage.Builder imBuild = new InstantMessage.Builder();

        imBuild.Message = txtEnterText.Text;
        imBuild.TimeStampTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        InstantMessage im = imBuild.BuildPartial();

        im.WriteTo(networkStream);
        ...
```

This works great. But at the other end, I'm having trouble getting the `ParseFrom` to work.

I want to use:-

```
InstantMessage im = InstantMessage.ParseFrom(networkStream);
```

But instead I have had to read it to bytes and then parse it from here. This is obviously not ideal for a number of reasons. Current code is:-

```
while (true)
        {
            Byte[] byteArray = new Byte[10000000];

            int intMsgLength;
            int runningMsgLength = 0;

            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

            while (true)
            {
                runningMsgLength += networkStream.Read(byteArray, runningMsgLength, 10000000 - runningMsgLength);

                if (!networkStream.DataAvailable)
                    break;

            }

            InstantMessage im = InstantMessage.ParseFrom(byteArray.Take(runningMsgLength).ToArray());
```

When I try to use `ParseFrom`, control does not return to the calling method even when I know a valid GB message is on the wire.

Any advice would be gratefully received,

PW

Comment: Dataavailable is a bad option here, btw. It tells you nothing about the actual data.

Comment: Will look into this tomorrow. Too tired tonight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for taking a while to answer this. As Marc says, protocol buffers don't have a terminator, and they aren't length prefixed unless they're nested. However, you can put on the length prefix yourself. If you look at MessageStreamIterator and MessageStreamWriter, you'll see how I do this - basically I *pretend* that I'm in the middle of a message, writing a nested message as field 1. Unfortunately when reading the message, I have to use internal details (BuildImpl).

There's now another API to do this: `IMessage.WriteDelimitedTo` and `IBuilder.MergeDelimitedFrom`. This is probably what you want at the moment, but I seem to remember there's a slight issue with it in terms of detecting the end of the stream (i.e. when there isn't another message to read). I can't remember whether there's a fix for it at the moment - I have a feeling it's changed in the Java version and I may not have ported the change yet. Anyway, that's definitely the area to look at.

Comment: Jon, apologies for the late response - I have been away on a training course.

Thanks for the tip - I had a brief look and I'm sure with that explanation I can figure it out.

Thanks again, I'm really grateful.

PW

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf has no terminator - so either close the stream, or use your own length prefix etc. Protobuf-net exposes this easily via SerializeWithLenghtPrefix / DeserializeWithLengthPrefix.

Simply: without this, it can't know where each message ends, so keeps trying to read to the end of the stream.

Comment: Thanks Marc,

I'm unclear where you're seeing the SerializeWithLengthPrefix and its corresponding Derserialize...

Are you saying I need to call a method on my InstantMessage object before doing:

im.WriteTo(networkStream); 

?

Thanks again

Comment: @phil - protobuf-net is a different implementation, but the same approach should work. There *may* be an existing method in Jon's version: I don't know for sure.